how to send extra data to Automapper
We have an entity type class that when it is converted to its dto class, I want a property to be set with additional calculations. Entity class:
 public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string  LastName { get; set; }
    public byte Score { get; set; }
}

Dto class:
public class StudentRankingDto
{
        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }  // FirstName +" " +LastName
    public string Rank { get; set; }
}

In Dto class, the rank attribute value is calculated based on a dictionary.
dictionary :
 Dictionary<byte,string> Ranks { get; set; } = new Dictionary<byte, string>() 
{
    {0,"rejected" },
    {1,"very weak" },
    {2,"very weak" },
    {3,"weak" },
    {4,"weak" },
    {5,"medium" },
    {6,"medium" },
    {7,"Good" },
    {8,"Good" },
    {9,"Excellent" },
    {10,"Excellent" }
};

And considering that the dictionary may change later due to the logic of the program and it is necessary not to have a fixed dictionary inside Automapper and this dictionary must be sent to Automapper. Now my question is: how to assign the rank attribute based on the student's score in Automapper by sending this dictionary?
And a more general question. If the value of the property to be calculated should be obtained from a database table, how is it possible to inject the database into Automapper with ef Core?
I tried to send an object based on the Automapper guide but it didn't work

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts. Sounds like a simple ForMember()/MapFrom() statement.

Just get rid of Automapper. Do it manually. It's more concise, simpler, and faster.

Just do this:
 public  static class AutomapperExtensions
 { 
     private static Dictionary<byte,string> Ranks { get; } = new Dictionary<byte, string>() 
     {
        { 0, "rejected" },
        { 1, "very weak" },
        { 2, "very weak" },
        { 3, "weak" },
        { 4, "weak" },
        { 5, "medium" },
        { 6, "medium" },
        { 7, "Good" },
        { 8, "Good" },
        { 9, "Excellent" },
        { 10, "Excellent" }
     };

     public static void CreateMapping(IMapperConfigurationExpression cfg)
     {
         cfg.CreateMap<Student, StudentRankingDto>()
          .ForMember(x => x.Name, 
              opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName)
          .ReverseMap();

         cfg.CreateMap<Student, StudentRankingDto>()
          .ForMember(x => x.Rank, 
              opt => opt.MapFrom(x => Ranks[x.Score])
          .ReverseMap();
     }
}

